# Parameters of a Cylinder

Tags: geometry, 3d

We know that cylinder is a 3D figure, and that 3D figures have 3 dimensions each. Different shapes have different parameters as well.

For example, parameters of the following:

- Cuboid - Length, Breadth, Height
- Cone - Radius, Height, Slant Height

Similary, what are the parameters of a **cylinder**. I know 2 of them - Height & Radius. What is the third (or any other) one?

***Update:*** I meant to say *parameters* instead of *dimensions*

Comment: The third one is the radius too!

Comment: Think for yourself: going by your logic, even a cone only has two dimensions, since once you fix its radius and height, the slant height is automatically fixed too...

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yes, I do agree that we can use the `Pythagoras Theorum` to calculate the slant height, which will be constant for any given cone. But it is still  a non-formula characteristic of the shape.

Comment: @MrigankPawagi Please define your meaning of "non-formula characteristic"

Comment: @GaurangTandon When I say a non-formula character, I mean that it shouldn't be the circumference, surface area, etc. that we derive using the *parameters* of the shape, and at times, with some constant like ***Pi***

Comment: How is $\sqrt{r^2 + h^2}$ **not** a formula of the parameters of a cone? Do you claim that a rectangle has three parameters: width $a,$ height $b,$ and diagonal $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$? Conversely, do you claim that a circle is one-dimensional because all its measurements can be derived from its radius?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing **3 dimensions** and the **number of parameters** a 3D object may have.

Every 3D object has a set of parameters that need to be determined to uniquely determine the magnitude of the object's dimensions. For a cuboid, there's three - length, height and breadth. For a cone and cylinder, you only need two. For a sphere, it's just one (its radius).

However, every 3D object extends in all 3 dimensions - x, y, and z - no matter how many parameters they have.

Hope that helps!

---

#### **Updated:**

As I said earlier, a cone also has only ***two*** parameters. And as you determined yourself even a cylinder has only two. As I've proved above in my answer **a 3D object may not necessarily have 3 parameters as well**.

Comment: Well, you are correct. I think that I should have written ***parameter*** instead of *dimension*

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @MrigankPawagi See updated,

Comment: This answer is correct. The entire premise of the question is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of what a "dimension" is, so there is an opportunity here for a major step forward in learning.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the reinforcement! Appreciate it ^_^